# Why is the heat death, rather than a Big Crunch, the most accepted theory of the ultimate fate of the Universe?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, universe, space-expansion, dark-matter

The Heat Death is accepted by most as the end of the Universe, but how can that be? Wouldn't the Big Crunch make a lot more sense? I mean, even if everything in the Universe is spread out uniformly and still expands (which is the Heat Death as far as I know), wouldn't gravity, even if extremely slowly, pull everything back together, so that the Big Crunch happens? Even if gravity gets a lot smaller the further something is away, there is still a minimal force left, which over time should lead to the Big Crunch, or not?

Comment: You seem to be starting from a false premise. Heat death and a big crunch are not a binary choice for the ultimate fate of the universe. We don't even really have a good way of describing the total entropy of the universe in cosmological models, so we don't have a way of formulating what heat death would even mean. Heat death is more of a Victorian way of looking at the issue.

Comment: I might be wrong, but i think i didn‘t Start with a binary choice, as my assumption was that even if the Heat Death would happen, then there could be a Big Crunch afterwards (unlike in binary, where one couldn‘t happen after the other, because that would be a new possibility, so trinary). Though now i got an answer why that shouldn‘t be possible as far as we understand the acceleration of expansion.

Comment: the big rip seems to be the way right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observational evidence indicates that the expansion of the universe is *accelerating*, not decelerating. In fact, according to the best cosmological model, it has been accelerating for the last five billion years.

The theoretical reason for the acceleration is believed to be *dark energy* uniformly filling the universe and providing a repulsive effect that exceeds the attractive effect of the matter and radiation in the universe.

There is no evidence to support a Big Crunch in our future.

Comment: Right, i think i read something about that (and that it has to do with Dark Matter/Energy or so)... that makes it impossible to overcome the velocity of expansion, since gravity gets weaker... totally forgot about that. Thanks^^

Comment: If you don’t get a better answer, please click the check mark to accept this one. Thanks.

Comment: I will, but it has a 10 minute cooldown before you can accept an answer (was still 6 minutes when i tried(2mins ago)(still 3 mins))^^

Comment: BTW, dark *matter* does *not* contribute to the acceleration. Dark matter is attractive, just like ordinary matter. The main difference is that it doesn’t have electromagnetic interactions so we can’t see it.

Comment: Yeah, just checked and apparently it‘s caused by Dark Matter (one of the possible causes).

Comment: I meant Dark Energy*... just realized i wrote Matter, but can‘t edit it anymore ^^